# Does TFS have a hook mechanism for taking action after branching to do things like automate editing a config file?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, version, branching-and-merging

I have a production branch. When I branch from this production branch I want to tap into a hooking mechanism to automate making changes in a config file. Like editing a connection string.

Does TFS provide this functionality that I think would be similar to client-side Git Hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't answer your question directly but another way to approach this is multiple config files in the solution and then have your deployment mechanism determine which once is actually deployed to each environment.

For example, you might have these in the solution all sitting next to each other.

1. Web.config.Development
2. Web.config.Test
3. Web.config.Production

During deployment the correct file would be chosen for each environment and then renamed to Web.config as it's getting pushed out.